# HTML child object doesnt get properties from parent object

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML, which is two pictures and a list of links:

```
<body class="wrapperGanzeSeite">
    <section class="introCard">
        <img id="Logo" src="LogoPulsamed.jpg"/>
        <img id="wasserBild" src="Wasserbild.jpg"/>              
    </section>
    <section class="wrapperSeitenMenü">
        <div class="menüHintergrund">
            <ul class="menüListe">
                <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Produkte</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Kontakt</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Gebrauchtgeräte</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Impressum</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>           
    <section class="Hauptteil">
    </section>
</body>
```

And I'm trying to set the height and width to maximum, and add a shadow to the bod. This is my CSS:

```
.wrapperGanzeSeite {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1400px;
    max-height: 1000px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #c7c7c7;
    margin: auto;
}
```

The pictures are working fine but the list is not showing inside the shadow even though the list tags are between the body tags. Help is really appreciated.

My full code is in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xw9pLef8/).

Comment: you need to give 100% height to the html too.. https://jsfiddle.net/xw9pLef8/1/

Comment: You know, you can just use body rather than .wrapperGanzeSeite

Comment: To show box-shadow in body, you will require to add padding in `html` like `html{padding:3px;} `
this should help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS - change:

```
.wrapperGanzeSeite
```

to

```
body, html
```

Comment: This answer would have been so much better if it also explained why.

Comment: Yeah, sorry :) I'll try to explain it..
When you create page, body and html are the size of elements inside. So if you open browser inspector, you will see that html has only height of your elements, and since your .wrapperSeitenMenü is floted (and there is no clear), its height it's not counted. In this case, body height is a 100% of html.

Comment: Also if you don't want page to be 100% height you can put some div after .wrapperSeitenMenü, when you set "clear:both" in css :)

Comment: Tried this out following Kate's remarks. https://jsfiddle.net/xw9pLef8/3/. @Kate: thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for creating a [menu](https://jsfiddle.net/xw9pLef8/2/) using UL and LI elements.

```
 <code>
    #menu:hover ul {
      display:block
    }

   ul{
      display:none;
   }
    </code>
```

Comment: yes this would be right if i want to make a dropdown menu. But here i tried to get a shadow around everything ;) But thanks to you too